# Is Kuvera Rākṣasendra? Where is Rākṣasendra mentioned in the Mahābhārata? What is the source [Ann.111]?

Tags: mahabharata, identification-request, sanskrit, ravana, rakshasa

Source: https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/rakshasendra. It says it means Rāvaṇa (I find this unlikely), or Kuvera (which would bring about more questions, but will also answer a few). Where in the Mahābhārata is Rākṣasendra mentioned?

From searching online, I find the majority of the "sources," claiming Rāvaṇa is Rākṣasendra claim  [Ann.111] as a source. These sources also claim that Rākṣasas are aboriginals, which does not make sense for a 101 different reasons, ranging from they are way, way too big (e.g. in the Kalki Purāṇa) to their ancestry clearly being different to humans. Thus, I'm doubtful this source is a good one.

e.g
Brahman: The Discovery of the God of Abraham
By Prof.M.M. Ninan

The book **A Classical Dictionary of Hindu Mythology and Religion, Geography, History ...
By John Dowson** mentions Rākṣasendra as Kuvera (twice). Does anyone have the full quotes from the book? (I only saw snipets)

Also, does anyone know if the idea that Kubera and Kuvera are the same is surported in scripture, or are their descriptions just similar due to Rākṣasas and Yakṣas doing everything together?

Comment: In Mahabharat, Rākṣasendra is used for Ghatotkacha and Alayudha and may be many more...bdw, what kind of Q is this?..I saw Qs here to find a story...but finding just a single word would be much difficult bcz few people read translated version in Hindi/English and such words would be replaced with actual names according to the context.."It says it means Rāvaṇa (I find this unlikely)," - why do you find it unlikely?

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the link Rakshasendra, consist of two words, Rakshas and Indra.
As per my understanding, when the term Indra is used with other terms, it signifies that for whomever the term is used for, he/she/it is superior to others of its kind or is like a king of its kind.

for instance:
**Devendra** is Indra within devas or king of Devas,
**Narendra** is Indra within all Nars (humans), or king of humans and **Gajendra** is Indra within all Gaja (Elephants) or king of elephants.

So the word Rakshasendra means an Indra within all Rakshas or king of Rakshas.
But it does not necessarily mean Ravana.
Because Ravan, though is the best example of the king of all Rakshas, Was king for the duration of limited time, Before him and after him, there must have been other kings as well.
like Bali, Prahalad, Hiranyakashpu, and many others.

So **Rakshasendra** is more like a designation rather than a name for a particular person.

Comment: I think Rākṣasendra is referring to a very specific thing, as any definitive identifications of someone as Race+Indra is very specific e.g. Garuḍa or Kubera. Also, Prahlāda is Daityendra. Also, all of the "Race + Indra,"s are deities.

Answer (score 0):

In order to support V. Aggarwal’s answer, I will show a few examples with sources:

In the Ramayana the word Rakshasendra is used many times to refers to Ravana. In verse 5.52.5:

> kṣamasva roṣam tyaja rākṣasendra prasīda madvākyamidam śṛṇuṣva |
> vadham na kurvanti parāvarajñā dūtasya santo vasudhādhipendrāḥ || 5.52.5
>
> “O King of the Titans, control thine anger and with a tranquil mind hear me, extend your favour to me. Righteous monarchs, being conversant with the laws of cause and effect, do not take the life of a messenger.”
>
> ([source](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424611.html))
>
> Alternative translation:
> “O king of demons! Forgive and give up your anger. Be gracious and hear my words. Virtuous kings of excellence, knowing the distant and the near, do not cause killing of an envoy.”
>
> ([source](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga52/sundara_52_frame.htm))

Note that in the same chapter, the synonym Rakshaseshvara is used.

In the Kathasaritsagara, the word is used two times as an epithet for Vibhishana, brother of Ravana.

First of all in verse 2.4.136:

> ekadā taṃ ca papraccha rākṣasendraṃ sakautukaḥ |
> laṅkāyāṃ kāṣṭhamayyeṣā kathaṃ sarvaiva bhūriti || 136 ||
>
> “One day he asked the King of the Rākṣasas, feeling curiosity on the point, why the whole ground of Laṅkā was made of wood; and Vibhīṣaṇa, when he heard that, explained the circumstance to him, saying:”
>
> Source ([English](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/kathasaritsagara-the-ocean-of-story/d/doc64311.html), [Sanskrit](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/kathasaritsagara-sanskrit/d/doc322833.html))

Now verse 18.2.242 better illustrates the use of the word "Rakshasendra" as an epithet:

> laṅkārājye 'bhiṣiktasya rākṣasendrasya mandire |
> vibhīṣaṇasya so 'tiṣṭhadratnahemamṛgo 'dbhutaḥ || 242 ||
>
> [...] and Vibhīṣaṇa having been set upon the throne of Laṅkā, as King of the Rākṣasas—that wonderful deer of gold and jewels remained in his palace [...]
>
> Source ([English](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/kathasaritsagara-the-ocean-of-story/d/doc143240.html), [Sanskrit](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/kathasaritsagara-sanskrit/d/doc342368.html))

Finally, in the Skandapurana verse 1.2.21.189, the word Rakshasendra is used to refer to Nirriti:

> skandhe garutmataḥ so'pi niṣasāda vicetanaḥ |
> khaḍgena rākṣasendraṃ ca bhittvā bhūmāvapātayat || 189
>
> “He hit Garuḍa in the shoulder, who sat down and became senseless. He split Rākṣasendra (i.e. Nirṛti) with a sword and made him fall on the ground.”
>
> source ([English](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc366007.html), [Sanskrit](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A7_(%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83)/%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8C%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A8%E0%A5%A7))

Comment: I'm not sure if it is talking about Rāvaṇa or Rākṣasa just use Rākṣasendra in their exclamations as people of the Abrahamic faiths do with their Gods. Also, in the Skandapurana reference you gave Rākṣasendra/Nirṛti is mentioned in the same way Gods are, which just increases my doubt of Rāvaṇa being Rākṣasendra.

Comment: Also from this I this, I think प्रसीद is indeclinable: http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D&lang=sans&action=Search.